# How to click a button in below HTML code using selenium+Java

Tags: selenium, button, webdriver, click

I tried with using `@class` but it throws exception saying this much large string cant be taken.

Not getting which selector need to use for this button click as `id`, `name` or button element is not present.

`HTML` Code

```
<div>
    <a class="hint--top-left download-button header-button" data-hint="Download" data-bind="attr : { href: $data.downloadUrl, download: $data.fileName }, css: { disabled : $data.errorContent() }" download="000075_wem_log_11032017.csv" href="blob:https://barrot.com/1dcbc880-89d8-4798-9682-87dace0ed1f8"></a>
</div>
```

If any one came across such situation, please throw a light on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use search `By.xpath` using below expression:

```
//a[@data-hint="Download"]
```

same with `By.cssSelector`:

```
a[data-hint="Download"]
```

Note that you cannot use `By.className` with compound names (`"hint--top-left download-button header-button"`), but you can choose one of them (e.g. `"download-button"`)

Answer (score 0):

If @Class is not working and if @Data-Hint='Download' is not unique then find any common attribute.

For eg: if @Data-Hint='download' is common across many elements then:

```
List<WebElement> element =driver.findElements(by.xpath(.//a[@Data-Hint='Download']));
element.get(index).click();
```

This should do the trick-Instead of index replace with 0-n, where "n" is the size of the List